# Argument never used

Tags: rust, clap

I am trying to just add another argument that prints the parsed results, not sure why this is resulting in this error:

```
src/main.rs:35:32
   |
35 |     println!("{:#?}", matches, if printparsed{ "" } else { "Cannot Parse Output"});
   |              -------           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument never used
```

Code here:

```rust
use clap::{App, Arg};

fn main() {
    let matches = App::new("rustecho")
    .version("0.1.0")
    .author("ElementalX")
    .about("echo")
    .bin_name("rustecho")
    .usage("rustecho <SOMETEXTHERE>")
        .arg(
            Arg::with_name("outputtext")
                .value_name("TEXT")
                .help("Input text")
                .required(true)
                .min_values(1),
        )
        .arg(
            Arg::with_name("omitnewline")
                .short("n")
                .help("Do not print newline")
                .takes_value(false),
        )
        .arg(
             Arg::with_name("parseoutput")
             .short("p")
             .help("Parse the arguments and print them"),
             
      )
        .get_matches();

    let text = matches.values_of_lossy("outputtext").unwrap();
    let omit_newline = matches.is_present("omitnewline");
    let mut parsedargs = matches.values_of_lossy("parseoutput").unwrap();
    let mut printparsed = matches.is_present("parseoutput");
    println!("{:#?}", matches, if printparsed{ "" } else { "Cannot Parse Output"});
    print!("{}{}", text.join(" "), if omit_newline{ "" } else { "\n"});

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using one format specifier(`#?`) with two arguments. If you intended to [pretty print both `matches` and the string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#sign0)(based on the condition), you can wrap it in a tuple.

```
println!("{:#?}", (matches, if printparsed{ "" } else { "Cannot Parse Output"}));
```

Alternatively you can use multiple format specifiers.

```
println!("{:#?} {}", matches, if printparsed{ "" } else { "Cannot Parse Output"});
```